# inserting values of dictionary in different rows inside a table in mysql

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary

I am having a dictionary with multiple values for each key.
This dictionary is getting generated after parsing a log file.

```
([('RUNID', ['11098782', '11098782']), ('Test', ['OMP', 'AMP']), ('SubType', ['LU', 'BU']), ('Class', ['C', 'A']), ('Size', ['162', '64']), ('Iterations', ['250', '250']), ('Time', ['839.76', '44.30'])])
```

Number of keys are going to be same but the values pertaining to each key may `change(In the example above it is 2 and can be even more)` I had already created a table in MySQL having Columns as my `Keys(Runid,Test,Subtype,Class,Size,Iterations,Time)` of the dictionary. Now i want to insert the key `values(11098782,OMP,LU,C,162,250,839.96)` corresponding to each key in single row inside the database. Same with the next row with different `values(1109872,AMP,BU,A,64,250,44.30)` Any help is appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your list to a `dict`.

Then `zip` dict's values to get a list of your desired result.

**Note**: you should fix your `sql`, make the `values` in the corresponding order of the `keys`.

```
>>> b = ([('RUNID', ['11098782', '11098782']), ('Test', ['OMP', 'AMP']), ('SubType', ['LU', 'BU']), ('Class', ['C', 'A']), ('Size', ['162', '64']), ('Iterations', ['250', '250']), ('Time', ['839.76', '44.30'])])
>>> b = dict(b)
>>> zip(*b.values())
[('LU', '11098782', '250', '839.76', 'OMP', 'C', '162'), ('BU', '11098782', '250', '44.30', 'AMP', 'A', '64')]
>>> b.keys()
['SubType', 'RUNID', 'Iterations', 'Time', 'Test', 'Class', 'Size'] # order matters
```